# How to give a recursive definition and a direct formula and prove that they both are equivalent.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

How to give a recursive definition and a direct formula and prove that they both are equivalent.

for example, 10,13,16,19,22,25

I know the formula for this is a,a+d,a+2d,a+3d,...

7,49,343,2401,16807 ,the formula is a,$a^2$,$a^3$,,,,,

but what about recursive definition ?

Comment: Think about what you do to go from $7$ to $49$, from $49$ to $343$, etc...

Comment: The problem you are having is you are using the $...$ expression instead of $a_n=f(n)$ expression, when you introduce $n$ instead of using $...$ you will find it straightforward to come up with the recursive definition as well.

Comment: @JairTaylor I wrote down $7^1$ , $7^2$,.... but I am not sure if that's the recursive formula or direct formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define
$$a_k=a_0+kn$$
Then,
$$a_k-a_{k-1}=a_0+kn-(a_0+(k-1)n)=n$$
$$\iff a_k=n+a_{k-1}$$
Try using the same concept on the geometric series.

Comment: but how can I prove it ?

Comment: that recursiveformula is equivalent to direct formula?

Comment: @guest11 That is a proof. I simply used what was given to get $a_k$ in terms of $a_{k-1}$, which is the definition of a recursive relation.